# ASP Net Core Razor pages with Kendo DateTimePicker not upating model

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, kendo-asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I have a razor page displaying the control:

```
<div>
     @(Html.Kendo().DateTimePickerFor(model => model.StartDate)
        .Events(e => e.Change("endDatetimepickerChange"))
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 49%; float: left;" }))
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
    @(Html.Kendo().DateTimePickerFor(model => model.EndDate)
        .Events(e => e.Change("endDatetimepickerChange"))
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 49%; float: right;" }))
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate)
</div>
```

and the backing model has the two properties:

```
[BindProperty]
public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

[BindProperty]
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
```

The page displays as expected but the model is never updated when the value is changed on the control.

Also, both of my change scripts execute when the value changes and there are no errors in the console.

What am I missing here to get this control to post the changes back to the model?

Comment: How was the class definition where `StartDate` and `EndDate` looks like? Did that class inherits `PageModel`? You may also include `endDatetimepickerChange` function definition if necessary.

Comment: Yes the model is derived from PageModel.

Comment: My endDatetimepickerChange doesn't do anything right now. Do I need to implement posting the data back my self? What I would really like to do is create a button to update the page based on the selected start and end times. something like `<a asp-page="./Index" asp-route-start="@Model.StartDate" asp-route-end="@Model.EndDate" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Update</a>`

Comment: However, the button only receives the initial values of start and end, not the updated values.

Comment: In your change event, `$("#StartDate").val()` should have the current value.